# TKinter issue with gaining radiobutton value

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a function defined which holds 4 radiobuttons which contain answers to randomly asked questions, and I have another function which checks whether the selected radiobutton holds the correct answer, and if so, add 1 the variable "score", however, the score variable doesn't increment correctly, and seems to update randomly:

```
def answers():
    global text, rb1, rb2, rb3, rb4, v

    v = int() 

    rb1 = Radiobutton(root, text="One", variable=v, value=1, bg = "white", font = ("Segoe UI", 11))
    rb1.place(x=20, y=80)

    rb2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Two", variable=v, value=2, bg = "white", font = ("Segoe UI", 11))
    rb2.place(x=20, y=120)

    rb3 = Radiobutton(root, text="Three", variable=v, value=3, bg = "white", font = ("Segoe UI", 11))
    rb3.place(x=20, y=160)

    rb4 = Radiobutton(root, text="Four", variable=v, value=4, bg = "white", font = ("Segoe UI", 11))
    rb4.place(x=20, y=200)

    next() 





def next():   
    val=(int(v))

    if question_variable == "Describe what the instruction 'BRP' does.":
        rb1['text'] = "If the contents of the accumulator are zero or positive, set the program counter to address xx."
        rb2['text'] = "If the contents of the accumulator are zero only, set the program counter to address xx."
        rb3['text'] = "If the contents of the accumulator are positive only, set the program counter to address xx."
        rb4['text'] = "If the accumulator is empty, set the program counter to address xx."
        if val == 1: 
            score += 1


    elif question_variable == "Describe what is meant by the term 'Open Source Software'.":
        rb1['text'] = "Open source software is software that is paid-for only."
        rb2['text'] = "Open source software is software that is free."
        rb3['text'] = "Open source software is software with source code that anyone can inspect, modify, and enhance."
        rb4['text'] = "Open source software is copyrighted software."
        if val == 3:
            score += 1

    elif question_variable == "What is meant by the term 'Lossy Compression'?":
        rb1['text'] = "Lossy compression is a compression method that removes metadata from the file, resulting in smaller file sizes."
        rb2['text'] = "Lossy compression is a compression method that works by removing redundant and unrequired data."
        rb3['text'] = "Lossy compression is a compression method which reduces the file size without any noticeable quality loss."
        rb4['text'] = "Lossy compression is a risky compression method which could result in data corruption if used incorrectly."     
        if val == 2:
            score += 1

    elif question_variable == "What is the number '55' as an 8-bit unsigned binary integer?":
        rb1['text'] = "00110111"
        rb2['text'] = "11101100"
        rb3['text'] = "11001011"
        rb4['text'] = "00110100"
        if val == 1:
            score += 1

    elif question_variable == "What might a printer use RAM for?":
        rb1['text'] = "To store its OS."
        rb2['text'] = "To store most frequently printed pages."
        rb3['text'] = "To hold the current and subsequent jobs."
        rb4['text'] = "To take RAM load off the main computer."
        if val == 3:
            score += 1

    elif question_variable == "Describe the term 'firewall'.":
        rb1['text'] = "A firewall prevents harmful software from accessing a computer."
        rb2['text'] = "A firewall redirects data packets via other nodes before reach its designated computer."
        rb3['text'] = "A firewall limits the speed that the packets are able to travel at."
        rb4['text'] = "A firewall enforces a set of rules about what data packets will be allowed to enter or leave a network."
        if val == 4:
            score += 1

    else:
        rb1['text'] = "Memory Address Register"
        rb2['text'] = "Arithmetic Logic Unit"
        rb3['text'] = "Memory Data Register"
        rb4['text'] = "Accumulator"
        if val == 4:
            score += 1
```

Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Why you defined two functions with the same name?

Comment: @KarimNGorjux sorry my bad. Corrected it

Answer (score 1):

Since `v` is a global variable, you shouldn't have to represent it as another variable in your if statements that decide what button is pressed.  Also, `v` is already and integer, so you don't have to use the `int()` function in `val` either

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Even after correcting the above issues, the problem still persists. For example, when asked to "Describe what is meant by the term 'Open Source Software'.", even upon selecting the 3rd radiobutton, which is the correct one, the score still doesn't increment.

Comment: When you say it doesn't increment correctly, does that mean it never or sometimes increments?

Comment: It sometimes increments, even when pressing the incorrect radiobutton, it'll still increment

Comment: Look at Brian Oakley's answer.  Basically you just need to run the get() command in your if statements e.g. `if rb1.get() == 1:`  You might have to check all the buttons on each question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a normal python variable for the `variable` parameter. Since you're using integer values, it needs to be an instance of `IntVar`. To get the value you'll need to call the `get()` method on that instance.

Comment: Even after implementing this, which happens to be the system I had before deciding to scrap it, it still doesn't work, and seems to increment the score almost randomly

Comment: @FirasHafiz: when I replace `v=int()` with `v=IntVar()`, and replace `val=(int(v))` with `val=v.get()`, and then add missing code, your radiobuttons works fine.

Comment: I did exactly the same and still get issues. Is it OK If I send you my entire code? Because I'm about to give up on this